# Comments are missing in SQL script during GitHub deployment

Tags: git, visual-studio, github

I have written a SQL Server stored procedure with lot of comments. However, when I am merging the changes from local to acceptance/production environment in Visual Studio via GitHub, the comments are automatically erased in the destination. Comments are present in BUILD (Get deploy.sql) if I check in GitHub, but not after that. Could you please suggest any ideas to get the comments in the acceptance/production environment?

Comment: Thats nothing to do with SQL Server - untagged.

Comment: *Git* does not do this; you must be using some auxiliary add-on software that does it.

Comment: @torek, I am not using any software other than Visual Studio 2022 with GitHub extension.

Comment: That's an auxiliary add-on as far as Git is concerned. Maybe you want to remove the [tag:git] tag here?